# WPF/MVVM - should view-models stay constant and just the model change?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm a bit in doubt as to what is 'the right way'.

I have an application with concepts like visual studio, so I'll use that to explain:

I have a 'solution' view model and a model behind. The view model is displayed in a 'explorer'.

I can change between the situations where 'no solution is loaded' to 'a solution is loaded' and back.

And finally my question :-) :

Should I keep my view model object and let it reflect that I have a new 'solution object' loaded? Or should I create a new view model object and let the view bind to the new object?

Comment: It really depends on how you have arranged you `ViewModel` class hierarchy. Could you provide details on that?

Comment: I will certainly try! I have a main window with corresponding vm, a user control for the 'explorer' with vm and I have set up the 'explorer' by mapping each level (project, code file) to each their vm. The 'solution' vm is double-connected to 'project' which is double-connected to 'code file'.
Was that the details you needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Viewmodel contains the state of any data associated with the UI which is not *further back* in the Model.

One way I answer questions such as yours is by considering what behaviour I want in the UI and what needs binding to some state information. Or, to put it a different way, any time that I feel like writing some code that would cause UI elements to be shown or hidden, think about how that maps to a boolean variable.

So, take large chunks of the UI that only are visible when you have a Model loaded. These might have their visibility bound to a boolean property in the Viewmodel IsSolutionLoaded.

Maybe you want to disable some things if processing is occurring, you could have a property IsCompiling. I've used this approach with a property NotRunningthreadedProcessing as shown below, that let me disable controls when a synchronisation object existed in the Viewmodel.

```
CNTL_WhiteLevel.SetBinding(ProgressBar.IsEnabledProperty, 
    new Binding("NotRunningThreadedProcessing"));

// and the C++/CLI property concerned
property bool NotRunningThreadedProcessing {
    bool get()
    {
        return mThreadedCommandSyncher == nullptr;
    }
};
```

Comment: Hi Andy,
Thanks for responding! As I read your answer, you would keep the instance of the 'solution'-vm and update the 'solution'-model, thus letting the same instance of the vm respond differently to the gui?

Comment: Hi Andy and Saurabh, in the end I kept the view model object if I had one and updated the reference to model. The view model objects implement INotifyPropertyChanged so all I had to do was call PropertyChanged on the bound values. Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 1):

What is the arrengement of the ViewModel?

In General

View Model is the localized version of actualmodel and View is updated whenever there is a change i its viewModel through DataBiding.

in your case ,you have 2 states.

1- Your View is Loaded

2- Your View is not loaded

**so should I create a new view model object and let the view bind to the new object?**

in my thoughts ,YES